# Remove text between two parenthesis, if two more parenthesis

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this string:

`"This thing (123, 12) (2005.03 - 2011.12)"`

I want to convert it to:

`"This thing (2005.03 - 2011.12)"`

Meaning remove text between two first parenthesis: `(123, 12)`. But only if there are two or more parenthesis following in same string. So a string like

`"Another thing (2005.05 - 2011.08)"`

should be left as it is.
How can I do it with javascript?

Comment: your question is not clear though.
but as far as i am concerned you can first convert all string to chars array and count i there is count greater then four  then yuo use index of first parenthesis the from that string you find the next one.

Comment: @JaromandaX Invalid regular expression flags error.

Comment: the regexp was correct (not the best as per the answer) - the problem is how the regexp appeared in the comment due to \ characters -

Comment: what about `"This thing (123, 12) (2005.03"` or `"This thing (123, 12) hello world (2005.03 - 2011.12)"` - what happens in these cases?

Comment: @JaromandaX will not happen

Comment: Good, so the parenthesis will always be paired `()` and only white space between `)` and `(` - that does make both answers viable solutions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use String.replace() with regex like this https://regex101.com/r/X7ioxu/1

```
var regex = /(\(.+?\))\s?\(/g;
var str1 = "This thing (123, 12) (2005.03 - 2011.12)";
var str1 = "This thing (2005.03 - 2011.12)";

alert(str1.replace(regex,'('));
alert(str2.replace(regex,'('));
```

Comment: great answer, How would it be if I dont want to match if there are both digits and numbers inside braces?

Comment: I'm not sure if I get you right. Could you please give example, like input and output?

Answer (score 1):

With the data given, this works

```js
var str = "This thing (123, 12) (2005.03 - 2011.12)";


var parts = str.split(/(?=\()/g); // split on ( with lookahead
if (parts.length==3) parts.splice(1,1)
str = parts.join("")
console.log(str)
```